# Java - Regex to get the value after a particular string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the value between quotes for a particular string
For example, for the 'IsEmployee' key, I need to get the value 'Yes'

id:'1234',Salary:'200000',Year:'2018',IsEmployee:'Yes'
can anyone please share any sample regex for this

Comment: Is this a JSON file?

Comment: no. It is just a string.

Comment: Ok then what about `\bIsEmployee:'([^']+)'`?

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code/regex and explain what you it returns vs what you expect it to return.

Answer (score 1):

It seems JSON format, although as a string. Please use JSON parser for more flexibility to get any value by keys, or print all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexpApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String val = "id:'1234',Salary:'200000',Year:'2018',IsEmployee:'Yes'";
        System.out.println(getValue(val, "id"));
        System.out.println(getValue(val, "Year"));
        System.out.println(getValue(val, "IsEmployee"));

    }

    public static String getValue(String testStr, String key){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+key+"[ ]*:[ ]*'(.+?)'");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testStr);
        return  m.find() ? m.group(1): null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?i)(?<=isemployee:')[^']*
```

[**Click for Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Nk4NlB/1/)

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - makes the regex case-insensitive
- `(?<=isemployee:')` - positive lookbehind to find the **position** which is just preceded by `isemployee:'`
- `[^']*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `'`. In short, it matches everything until the next `'` is found in the string

**Code: [OUTPUT](http://rextester.com/VMZAI24136)**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        final String regex = "(?i)(?<=isemployee:')[^']*";
        final String string = "id:'1234',Salary:'200000',Year:'2018',IsEmployee:'Yes'";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```